# Regular Expression to match part or all of a string

Tags: regex

I create a regular expression on the fly based on the results of a variable.  I've successfully tested most of the expression, but I'm struggling with the part that can vary in length.

How can I amend the regular expression `(a_)?c(davison)\.nsf?` so that any of the below strings would be classed as a match?

- a_cdavis.nsf
- cdavison.nsf
- cdaviso.nsf
- cdavis.nsf

Essentially, to be considered a match, strings must meet the following criteria -

1. **"(a_)?"** - May start with "a_" but doesn't have to
2. **"c"** - Must contain the lowercase letter "c"
3. **"(davison)"** - *The bit I can't do*  - Must contain part or all of "davison", starting at the beginning (so "dav" is acceptable, but "son" is not)
4. **".nsf"** - Must finish with ".nsf"
5. **Length** - Be no more than 12 characters in length, including the optional "_a" at the beginning of the string and the required ".nsf" at the end of the string.

Any hints and tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make each part of `davison` optional, use *nested optional groups* (`(?:...)?`), and to set the length restriction, you may use a negative lookahead anchored at the start to fail the match if 13 characters are found (thus, `(?!.{13})` will allow strings of 12 and fewer characters in size):

```
^(?!.{13})(a_)?c(d(?:a(?:v(?:i(?:s(?:on?)?)?)?)?)?)\.nsf$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR0dQ8/2)

Comment: Won't this also match `cson.nsf`? Quote: "(so "dav" is acceptable, but "son" is not)" I think you need `(d(a(v(...)?)?)?)?`

Comment: Is it not expected? If not, and the letters should always follow one another, `^(?!.{13})(a_)?c(d(?:a(?:v(?:i(?:s(?:on?)?)?)?)?)?)\.nsf$` can help.

Comment: It depends on what the language is. In JS, it would [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/rsLngq2g/).

Comment: The language (not through choice) is VBA, and I'm actually working on generating the regex right now...

Comment: I am going to have lunch now, if you have trouble with VBA code, just let me know.