# Regular expression to match everything that a word begins with

Tags: regex, python-2.7

All is in the title. I am looking for the best regular expression to do so.

As an example I could want, for a main word `John`, to match `J`, `Jo`, `Joh` and `John`.

One of my goals is to use it on month names such as `January` in different languages and with or without a first capital letter. So using the brutal solution `(J|Jo|Joh|John)` doesn't please me that much.

By the way, I just want to check if there is a match or not, and I don't care about what substring the match gives me back (if `John` raises `J`, i'm fine).

Comment: [`J(o(h(n)?)?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/wX5aO1/1)

Comment: See a [similar quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208205/regular-expression-to-match-part-or-all-of-a-string/37208292#37208292). Please precise:  your input is `John` and you want to find a match in `J`, `Jo`, `Joh`, and `John`? You should just build the pattern Avinash supplied for each case programmatically (which can be done in Python more or less easily).

Comment: Sure, I eventually came up with that too. I was curious to see if there was any better solution. Thank's.

Comment: If you want to do it for generic words you'll need to 
(1) Substring your primary word into letters
(2) Build the Avinash Regex based on the letters in (1)

Comment: Why don't you just use [startwith()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm) ?

Comment: I was including it in a more global regex framework, but this is actually a good idea to make an exception here. Thank's.

Comment: [Is this something near what you need?](http://ideone.com/YWbcal)

Comment: While regex may help you in a lot of string manipulation, sometimes it's great to come back to good old native functions

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know `startswith`, but it trivializes my problem (and is quick). I'm glad I asked here.

Comment: @Druzion Be care, your regex matches the empty string ;)

Comment: I'm not clear about your input and output. Do you want to match any starswith of a word(like 'John') in a string(like "July at Johannesburg") ?

Comment: For example yes. But in my work i was adding separators to recognize them as words, not to match your example, but e.g. "J like Jordan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summering up :**

- *Regex-or-nothing* solution : `J(o(h(n)?)?)?`
- *Python String* solution : [startwith()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm).